# Headphones always detected (plugged in) and no sound after BIOS reset itself

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, bios, headphones

My laptop is Acer Predator Helios 500 PH517-51

- Dual boot Windows 10, Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu 18.04
- Laptop headphones jack always detected as plugged in.
- No sound in headphones.
- `pavucontrol` , `alsamixer` , `hdajackretask` can't solve problems.
- HDMI and Display port have no sound too.
- In Windows 10 everything work fine.

> I have this problem after run out of battery during updating Windows
>   10. I did plug in and boot my laptop again found it continue updating. After update finished it can't boot to Windows & Ubuntu so I found
>   BIOS reset itself to default setting. I config it agian (SATA mode, Secure boot) then found these problem.

[image: pavucontrol image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and here is how to solve it (I hope :p) :
Edit the config file of tlp at /etc/default/tlp (I hope it's the same for ubuntu) and check the following values :

```
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_AC = 1 [this might be zero by default]
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT = 1
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_CONTROLLER = Y
RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC = auto [this one is disabled by default]
```

This solution was discovered by Toolfox, go to see the original thread [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=243004)